# Нет столбца с именем sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite3

```
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
sql = db.cursor()

sql.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    login TEXT, 
    password TEXT,
    cash BIGINT
)""")
db.commit()

user_login  = input('login: ')
user_password = int(input('password: '))
sql.execute("SELECT login FROM users")
if sql.fetchone() is None:
    sql.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES (?, ?)", (user_login, user_password))
    db.commit()
    print('Registered!')
else:
    print('Such note is already in database!')
```

вот код, а вот ошибка:
sql.execute("SELECT login FROM users")
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: login

Comment: `IF NOT EXISTS` - а если `EXISTS`? Попробуйте удалить файл БД.

Answer (score 0):

Лично я не создавал столбцы в базе данных через код, поетому я вам ничем не помогу, но могу дать совет как делаю это я
Я нашел и скачал программу [SQLiteStudio](https://sqlitestudio.pl/) и когда код создает базу данных, я вручную через програму создаю столбцы, а потом их просто заполняет код

Comment: Спасибо, в будущем прислушаюсь к вашему совету!)

Answer (score 0):

```
with sqlite3.connect('server.db') as db:
  sql = db.cursor()

  sql.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    login TEXT, 
    password TEXT,
    cash BIGINT
  )""")
```

Comment: Объяснте решение, пожалуйста.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!